# passing value to a different webpage form

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web

I'm trying to learn to make a webapp using JavaScript along side with nodejs. I'm all out of ideas and have no clue if im doing this correctly. So what im trying to do is when a user clicks on a row of a the dynamically created table it opens up a new html page with a bunch of form inputs already filled in with the values in a json. Right now I have it that when I click on the table row I can get the Id chosen and as a test i want to load it in to a input field but im getting it as undefined

a good portion of the table creating function with the fillform function

```
    for (i = 0; i < attendee.length; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        if(i % 2 == 0)
        {
            tr.bgColor = '#E9F2F5';
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < attendee[i].length; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('TD');

           /* if (j != 0) {
                td.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
            }*/
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(attendee[i][j]));
            tr.appendChild(td);

            var currentRow = table.rows[i];
            var createClickHandler =
                function(tr)
                {
                    return function() {
                        var cell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                        var id = cell.innerHTML;
                        fillForm(id);
                    };
                };
            currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
        }
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    }
    myTableDiv.innerHTML = "";
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
}

// this function is included in the html page as a onload function
function fillForm(id) 
{
    window.open("/populatedForm.html");
    document.getElementById("id").value = id;
    console.log(id);
}
```

Part of the html input I want to fill out.

```
<div class=container2>
    <form method="PUT" action="/process-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
        <fieldset>
            <label>
                ID<br/>
                <input id="id" name="id" type="text" value=" " required/>
            </label>
            <br/>
```

This is how my table looks like
[image]

And this is how the input looks like when I click on a row in the table. It opens the new html page but the input is set to undefined. I havent done the rest since I cant get id to work. 
[image]

Any advice would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a store or anything to save state on your webpage?  I think what is happening that you can't exactly tell from the code is when the new webpage comes up it is a fresh page with no state.  Is this a single page application?  If it's not you really will have to send a parameter through the url, or decide on another way to pass it to the page, you could also use a browser storage to store state, although I highly recommend passing it by parameter.

Comment: No i dont have a storage I guess. It is not a single page app. But I did look in to the browser storage (local storage is what im guessing you mean) and I just tried it and it worked for the Id input ill have to try it for the other ones. But is it safe to be using local storage?

Comment: It's got it's problems, I would highly recommend passing the variables as a parameter in the URL and grabbing it from there though.  I think part of the issue you are having is putting business logic and lots of it on the front end, when you should be doing it from the server.  I would recommend looking in routing server-side and client-side and finishing this project from there.

Comment: I totally understand what you're saying. I think you're idea about doing it server side is the more professional/nicer way of doing it. I will look in to outing server-side and client-side because I have no clue on how to do that. Thanks @MorganG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to further answer this down here as it is too long for me to post in the comments.

Once you figure out how to do routing you won't want to do it another way, here is a great resource http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html .  Look at the route parameters section.

So what I would do is have a route like `/populatedForm/:id`.  In express it will look something like this.

```
app.get('/populatedForm/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.params);
});
```

**req.params** will grab the id you want to grab, and then where it says **res.send()** is where you can handle all the business logic from that route.  That is where I'd make a call out to the database to grab all the information for that ID, and then send it as a json, then handle the JSON on your front end.

it'd look something like this

```
app.get('/populatedForm/:id', function(req, res) {
  var myJson = getIdAndOtherInfoFromDatabase(req.params);
  res.send(myJson);
});
```

Then you can handle all of it on the front end via JSON.  I would google around a bit about this stuff if you get confused or stuck.